# java jackson parse json array

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I need help with parsing, I've tried to create a different kind of model classes, but no use, please help me out here. the json looks like this:

```
[
  [
    1518909300000,
    "0.08815700",
    "0.08828700",
    "0.08780000",
    "0.08792900",
    "1727.93100000",
    1518910199999,
    "152.11480375",
    5118,
    "897.71600000",
    "79.04635703",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    1518910200000,
    "0.08788400",
    "0.08824200",
    "0.08766200",
    "0.08810000",
    "1789.81300000",
    1518911099999,
    "157.20177729",
    6201,
    "898.89500000",
    "78.95697080",
    "0"
  ]
]
```

and I'm trying to parse it using data class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class KlineResponse {

    public List<Kline> getKlineList() {
        return klineList;
    }

    public List<Kline> klineList;

    public class Kline {
        @JsonProperty("4")
        Double close;

        @JsonProperty("8")
        Integer tradesNumber;

        public Double getClose() {
            return close;
        }

        public void setClose(Double close) {
            this.close = close;
        }

        public Integer getTradesNumber() {
            return tradesNumber;
        }

        public void setTradesNumber(Integer tradesNumber) {
            this.tradesNumber = tradesNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

and this line

```
mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), new TypeReference<List<KlineResponse>>(){})
```

or

```
mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), KlineResponse.class)
```

but each time the error:
Can not deserialize instance of pt.settings.model.KlineResponse out of START_ARRAY token,
please help

Comment: Where's the definition of `Kline`? This looks like a normal class, so you can parse an array of string/number values into a List of `Kline`...

Comment: Kline is an inner class inside of KlineResponse, take a closer look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core issue is that you receive an array of arrays where you expect and array of objects. Changing `mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), KlineResponse.class)` to `mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), Object[].class)` confirms it.

You have a couple of options on how to proceed:

1. Change from Jackson to standard JSON parsing, as suggested by @cricket_007 on his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49050935/9025164)
2. Instead of mapping it to an object try to access the JSON differently. See @jschnasse's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49052409/9025164) for an example.
3. Change the format of text you parse, if you can
4. If you can't change the format of the input then you can either

   - Create a constructor and annotate it with @JsonCreator, like instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27332863/9025164)
   - Parse the input as Object array and feed the parsed array into a constructor of your own

Comment: marked your answer as the one, containing a bigger amount of solutions. as for me I've done it using array of arrays.

Comment: Did I use another parser? I used fasterxml.jackson 2.8

Comment: @jschnasse Sorry, my bad. Edited the relevant line.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any java classes. There are no JSON objects to deserialize, only arrays.

In the second case, Jackson is expecting `{ "klineList": [] }`

In the first, `[{ "klineList": [] }, { "klineList": [] }]`

And a Kline object is only parsable as `{"4": 0.0, "8": 0 }` (replace zeros with any value of same type)... So really unclear why you expected that to work given that data... The annotations **are not** the index of the lists.

Plus, your lists have both strings and integers, so you can only deserialize as `TypeReference<List<List<Object>>>`, then iterate that to parse ints, floats, or strings

I might recommend you use a standard json parser, not an objectmapper

Answer (score 1):

Use [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) together with [JPointer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-json-pointer-03). Avoid to create a POJO and work directly on the data via JsonNode.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode matrix = mapper.readValue(in, JsonNode.class);
matrix.forEach(array -> {
    System.out.println("Next Values:");
    System.out.println(array.at("/4").asDouble());
    System.out.println(array.at("/8").asInt());
});
```

Prints

```
Next Values:
0.087929
5118.0
Next Values:
0.0881
6201.0
```